# Use static method to build immutable type (org.apache.commons.lang3.Range<Long>)

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
class RangeDTO {
  public org.apache.commons.lang3.Range<Long> range;
}

class SourceDTO {
  public Long min;
  public Long max;
}

public interface Mapper {
    @Mapping(target = "range.max", source = "max")
    @Mapping(target = "range.min", source = "min")
    public abstract RangeDTO map(SourceDTO source);
}
```

This mapper method produces `Range<Long> does not have an accessible constructor error` (it's fine, `Range` doesn't have an accessible constructor) because it must created using static method [Range#between()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html#between-T-T-).

I prefer not to use `expression` nor writing a `Range<Long> map(SourceDTO)`.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm just going off memory here (hence why a comment and not an answer), but could something like `defaultExpression="java(org.apache.commons.lang3.Range.between(source.min, source.max))"` work for your?

Comment: `expression` definitely works, but I'm looking for a solution without `expression`